# Why can't I import using alias? Ex: `from tf import keras`

Tags: python, alias

I would simply like to understand why a call for `keras` like `from tf import keras` will not work in the following code, while I am already importing `tensorflow` as `tf` in the first line?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tf import keras
```

Error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'

However, the following would work -

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the [`import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) is responsible for finding your modules in the first place. It doesn't look in your current name space for variable bindings, which is where the alias `tf` is stored. This can also be thought of as your alias never renaming the target module:

```
>>> import sys as s
>>> s.__name__
'sys'
```

If `keras` is already an available name (as if any code had done `import tensorflow.keras`), you can still find that name within the imported module, so you could do something like `keras = tf.keras` then.

You can think of `import foo as bar` as a combination of `import foo ; bar = foo ; del foo`, except it never actually used the name `foo` in your local namespace.

It is possible, but quite awkward, to find the submodule using the given alias as well:

```
import importlib
import sys

import http as h
# Module name lookup method 1:
name = [k for (k,v) in sys.modules.items() if v is h][0]
# Module name lookup method 2:
name = h.__name__
c = importlib.import_module('.client', name)
```

Method 1 searches all currently imported modules to find the one that `is h`, which produces its imported (not just local) name, and uses a relative import from that. Quite likely method 2 also suffices, but it may not in case e.g. that entry has been deleted.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful! I will read through the documentation for further details.